# Как добавить свой текст к переменной, полученной из поля ввода

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно добавить кастомный текст к переменной, которая получается из ввода пользователя. Вот сам js код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var addDelivery = '';
if($('.radio_delivery_group').length) {

    setValue($('.radio_delivery_group input[type=radio]:checked'));

    $('.radio_delivery_group input[type=radio]').on('change', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        setValue($this);
    })

}

function setValue($this) {
    var $insertArea = $('.custom_address_shipping input[type=text]');
    if( $this.attr('data-val') === '0' ) {
        $insertArea.val('Самовывоз');
        $('.nova_posta_wrap').fadeOut(200);
        $('.courier_delivery_wrap').fadeOut(200);
    } else if( $this.attr('data-val') === '1' ) {
        $insertArea.val(addDelivery);
        $('.courier_delivery_wrap').fadeOut(200);
        $('.nova_posta_wrap').fadeIn(200);
    } else if( $this.attr('data-val') === '2' ) {
        $insertArea.val(addDelivery);
        $('.courier_delivery_wrap').fadeIn(200);
        $('.nova_posta_wrap').fadeOut(200);
    }

}

$('.city_select-2, .department_select-2').select2();
$('.city_select-2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var ref = $(this).val();
    getDepartment(ref);
    addDelivery += e.params.data.text;
});

$('.department_select-2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    addDelivery += ', ' + e.params.data.text;
    $('input[name=shipping_address_1]').val(addDelivery);
    console.log(addDelivery);
});


function getDepartment(ref) {
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json",

        },
        "processData": false,
           "data": "{\r\n\"apiKey\": \"90aa06b37d2015aef8490e13db746faf\",\r\n \"modelName\": \"AddressGeneral\",\r\n \"calledMethod\": \"getWarehouses\",\r\n \"methodProperties\": {\r\n \"CityRef\": \""+ ref +"\"\r\n }\r\n}"
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        // console.log(response);
        $('select[name=department]').html('<option>Выбрать отделение</option>');
        response.data.forEach(function (value) {
            var data = {
                id: value.SiteKey,
                text: value.DescriptionRu
            };
            var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, false);
            $('select[name=department]').append(newOption);
        });
    });
}});
```

этот код работает тут https://starterkit.com.ua/cart/ в блоке доставки.
логика работы: если выбрать **самовывоз** - поля не показываем, если выбрать **нова пошта** - показываем поля город/отделение, если выбрали курьером - показываем поле адрес.

Мне нужно когда вводится текст в поле "Курьером", чтобы он потом приходил с добавкой "доставка курьером" + текст, введенный пользователем.
Это поле потом фиксируется в заказе и мейле.

Comment: "как добавить свой текст к переменной" - элементарно. var X = 'переменная'; X + ' свой текст'

Answer (score 0):

Если сохранение происходит в бэкенде, то там и лучше добавлять надпись "доставка курьером". Если же надо обязательно отправлять в таком виде, то добавьте отслеживание отправки формы

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  var $courier = $(this).find('#radio_delivery_group_3');
  if($courier.is(':checked'))
  {
    var $address = $(this).find('#shipping_address_1');
    $address.val('доставка курьером' + address.val());
  }
})
```

Comment: спасибо, но ваш код выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: address is not defined в строке $address.val('доставка курьером' + address.val());

Comment: Опечатался, правильно: $address.val('доставка курьером' + $address.val()); Инициализирована переменная $address, а используется address поэтому и ошибка